# How to exclude NULL values inside CONCAT MySQL?

Tags: mysql, null, concat

If I have this - tadd is the `Address` table:

```
CONCAT(tadd.street_number, ' ',
            tadd.street_name,', ',
            tadd.apt_number,', ',
            tadd.city,', ',
            tadd.postal_code,', ',
            tadd.country) AS 'Address'
```

Is there a way to exclude the apt_number if it doesn't exist?

I was thinking of:

```
WHERE tadd.apt_number IS NOT NULL
```

But it will return only those rows with `apt_number`, and even if something works how do I then deal with that extra comma.

If it's a duplicate please post a link in comments.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you want to skip `NULL` values (but not empty strings), you can use **[`CONCAT_WS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)** function:

```
CONCAT_WS( ', ',            -- Separator
           CONCAT_WS(' ', tadd.street_number, tadd.street_name),
           tadd.apt_number,  tadd.city, 
           tadd.postal_code, tadd.country
         ) AS Address
```

From the docs:

> **`CONCAT_WS(separator,str1,str2,...)`**
>
> `CONCAT_WS()` stands for Concatenate With Separator and is a special form of `CONCAT()`. The first argument is the separator for the rest of the arguments. The separator is added between the strings to be concatenated. The separator can be a string, as can the rest of the arguments.  If the separator is `NULL`, the result is `NULL`.
>
> `CONCAT_WS()` does not skip empty strings. However, **it does skip any `NULL` values** after the separator argument.

Answer (score 10):

Convert `NULL` values in empty string by wrapping it in [`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) or [`IFNULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull):

### **IFNULL:**

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(IFNULL(tadd.street_number,''),
        ' ',IFNULL(tadd.street_name,''),
        ', ',IFNULL(tadd.apt_number,''),
        ', ',IFNULL(tadd.city,''),
        ', ',IFNULL(tadd.postal_code,''),
        ', ',IFNULL(tadd.country,'')) AS 'Address'
FROM db.tbl;
```

### **COALESCE:**

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(COALESCE(tadd.street_number,''), 
        ' ',COALESCE(tadd.street_name,''),
        ', ',COALESCE(tadd.apt_number,''),
        ', ',COALESCE(tadd.city,''),
        ', ',COALESCE(tadd.postal_code,''),
        ', ',COALESCE(tadd.country,'')) AS 'Address'
FROM db.tbl
```

Answer (score 3):

```
CONCAT(
    tadd.street_number, ' ', tadd.street_name, ', ',
-- concat() will return null if one is null, so ifnull returns empty string in that case
    IFNULL(CONCAT(tadd.apt_number, ', '), ''),
    tadd.city, ', ', tadd.postal_code, ', ',tadd.country
) AS 'Address'
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
CONCAT_WS('',         -- hack, empty delimiter
        tadd.street_number, ' ',
        tadd.street_name,', ',
        CONCAT(tadd.apt_number,', '), -- hack, this line will become NULL, when apt_number is null, and will be omitted with delimiter
        tadd.city,', ',
        tadd.postal_code,', ',
        tadd.country) AS 'Address'
```

I don't know **my**sql, but in **MS**SQL (TQSL) the solution looks like:

```sql
SELECT
        tadd.street_number + ' ' +
        tadd.street_name + ', ' +
        ISNULL(tadd.apt_number  + ', ', '') +
        tadd.city + ', ' +
        tadd.postal_code + ', ' +
        tadd.country AS 'Address'
```

Moreover, you can omit all `NULL` fields, not just apt_number (mysql again):

```sql
SELECT CONCAT_WS(', ',
        CONCAT(tadd.street_number, ' ', tadd.street_name),
        tadd.apt_number,
        tadd.city,
        tadd.postal_code,
        tadd.country) AS 'Address'
```